# Does leaving a barrel jack on a 9V battery drain the battery?

Tags: batteries

This is for when the barrel jack isn't plugged into anything. Just attached to the battery.

Comment: Which barrel jack?  A photo would help a lot here.  9V batteries do self-discharge over time, still in the package.  Some brands print a "use-by" date right on them.  The moment it is connected to *anything*, the lifespan will be at max the "use-by" date, and often less; even if whatever it's plugged into is not "on."

Answer (score 2):

If the barrel jack isn't connected to anything, it is just an open circuit - it will not drain the battery.

Comment: what if it's plugged into an unpowered wall wart? (my interpretation)

Comment: @dandavis: why would you connect a battery to a wall wart?  If you did connect a battery to an unpowered wall wart, the battery probably would not be discharged, but that depends on the circuitry in the wall wart.

Answer (score 1):

The barrel jack cable left connected on the battery would not cause it to drain.

[image]

The battery, having a shelf life, would deplete even if left alone unused.